# Limit definition by ordinal numbers

Tags: calculus

sorry if the question is stupid, but I've read for a while, in books like "Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy" by Bertrand Russell, and in his "Principia" that limits (the ones used in calculus) have a definition by ordinal numbers, and I would like to know that, because I studied a little of ordinal numbers in set theory and failed in seeing the connection. If you could give me a example using a simple function, like x², would be nice. I'm coursing Civil Engineering, so I would like to have a solid basis on the doctrine of Calculus, without the Weierstrass definition (that I found non informative). If you know another definition of limits too, I would be happy to know about.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I would say that you can get a solid basis in Calculus sufficient for Civil Engineering without ever getting *anywhere near* set theory! But it's good that you're so interested! :)

Comment: Where precisely does Russell say this? Even better if you have a quote, context may help understand what it is he has in mind.

Comment: 'It used to be thought that “limit”
was an essentially quantitative notion, namely, the
notion of a quantity to which others approached
nearer and nearer, so that among those others there
would be some diﬀering by less than any assigned
quantity. But in fact the notion of “limit” is a purelyordinal notion, not involving quantity at all (except
by accident when the series concerned happens to
be quantitative). A given point on a line may be the
limit of a set of points on the line, without its being
necessary to bring in co-ordinates or measurement
or anything quantitative.' Russell

Comment: It appears in Chapter X of "Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy" from Russell

Comment: This isn't about ordinal numbers, but about order: "ordinal" is just the adjective form of order, though not often used that way anymore. So $x$ can be "the" limit of a set $S$ of real numbers if for instance it's the least upper bound for $S$. I used scare quotes because it's not clear to me how to get a unique limit this way without ordering $S$, at which point one wants to say something about "for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$ $S$ is eventually in $N$" which is essentially a quantitative notion. It may be Russell doesn't have the same worries about "the" limit versus "a" limit that...

Comment: ...are natural to the modern eye in this situation.

Comment: Principia Mathematica, *207: "A term _x_ is said to be the "upper limit" of alpha in _P_ if alpha has no maximum and _x_ is the sequent of alpha. In this case, _x_ immediately follows the class alpha, though there is no one member of alpha with x immediately follows."

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this has anything to do with what Russell had in mind.

Let $T$ be the closed interval of ordinals $[0, \omega]$. The sequence $s_n$ has limit $L$ as $n \to \infty$ if and only if the function $S$ on the extended natural numbers defined by

$$ S(x) = \begin{cases} s_n & n \neq \omega \\ L & n = \omega \end{cases} $$

is continuous. This relies on using the general topological notion of to mean that the limit equals the value -- however, there is a more general definition of continuity for topological spaces:

> Choose topological bases for $X$ and $Y$. The function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at a point $P \in X$ if and only if, for every open neighborhood $V$ of $f(P)$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $P$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$

When $X=Y = \mathbf{R}$, the real numbers, the standard basis is that the open neighborhoods are the open intervals $(a, b)$ (including $(a, +\infty)$ and so forth). With a little work, you can see that the neighborhood $V$ corresponds to the interval $(L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon)$, and $U$ corresponds to $(P - \delta, P + \delta)$ in the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit.

But the point is that this definition works for any topology; in particular, it also makes sense when $X=T$: the basis open sets are again the intervals of ordinals. That is, they are the intervals $[a,b]$ ($a,b$ may be $\omega$).

The basis open neighborhoods of $\omega$ are thus the intervals $[N, \omega]$: unpacking the definition of continuity and the limit definition above then corresponds to the usual $\epsilon-N$ definition for $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = L$.

---

Aside: if you go searching, you will see the definition of continuous more commonly given in terms of open sets rather than in terms of a basis:

> $f : X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if, whenever $V$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

where $f^{-1}(V)$ is the set of all points $x$ such that $f(x) \in V$. The correspondence with bases is that a set $U$ is open if and only if, for every $P \in U$, there is a basis open neighborhood $V$ such that $P \in V \subseteq U$.

This definition is often a lot easier to reason about theoretically; but the basis version is often more useful when it comes to working with concrete examples.

There's an intermediate between the two definitions:

> $f : X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if, whenever $V$ is an open neighborhood of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

---

Note that, in both of our cases of interest, we choose a basis in terms of the usual ordering on our sets: i.e. we chose them to be intervals. Technically, in both cases we did choose them to be open intervals, but I didn't phrase it that way because it would require explaining why $[a,b]$ and $[a,\omega]$ are open, despite appearances. Also, I simplified a bit and didn't include $[a, \omega)$ in the basis, although I certainly could have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped for understanding the topological notions inside the limit definition. But I don't think that's what Russell had in mind; what I understand from his "Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy" is that he and Whitehead generalized the concept if limit for other types of ordered series, e.g, for classes that aren't "quantitative". Then, by this generalization, they can get the limit-definition for ordinal classes. When I read it, I directly go to the second volume of "Principia" to see the rigorous definition: I didn't understand sh*t, their notation requires

Comment: the reading of the previous pages, e.g, of the two other books. Than I thought it would be simpler to ask here for a simplified definition, without the lost of rigor of course. I could read the Principia and get to the definition, but I don't know if that's going to help me with my classes, and I don't want to "lose" all that time for knowing the limit definition in Principia and find out that doesn't suit pratical cases. That's why I asked an pratical example, so I can see how this generalized definition works in particular, so I can improve my knowledge on Calculus. Of course, I could just

Comment: be happy with Weierstrass definition and some topological similar ones, but, you know how humans are.. My mind wouldn't leave me in peace knowing there's a better generalized definition out there..